# How to flip integrated webcam horizontally. I require the mirrored effect (similar to the flip effect in cheese). thank you

Tags: ubuntu, camera, webcam, ubuntu-22.04, mirror

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
How can i horizontal flip my integrated webcam please, so the image is not inverted.
Thank you
I have tried creating a dummy webcam but cannot figure out how to do it. Appreciate your help

Expecting mirrored webcam feed